# How to recover a file from a tcpdump?

Tags: tcpdump

I use

```
tcpdump -i wlan0 -s 0 dst 192.168.1.200 or src 192.168.1.200 -w output.pcap
```

to monitor for ex.: my HTTP traffic.

I upload a .zip file through HTTP.

How can I retrieve the .zip file from the output.pcap file? Is it possible to recover it from there?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) could do this, although I've never done it myself.  Even if wireshark doesn't do it exactly I'd guess the answer to your second question is almost certainly "yes".  See also this [stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411911/is-there-a-way-to-programatically-export-files-using-wiresharks-facilities) which points to `tshark`.

Comment: yes. you can.  you just need a combination of tcpdump, tcpflow, and foremost.  there's a good writeup of this at: http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/558

Comment: I will try a bounty if there aren't any authorative answers :P

Comment: @jw013 I am pretty sure wireshark can do this. But I never used it for that purpose (and have no time to test it). I extracted an XML content from a http stream - so I would say: Most propably, yes. But I don`t want to get your reputation for this..

Answer (score 2):

[This list from ISC](http://isc.sans.edu/diary.html?storyid=6961) (and its comments) has a number of tools, one of which may fit your use case.

From my research on the ones in that list, the one by Brendan Gregg (of [DTrace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTrace) fame) is called [Chaosreader](http://chaosreader.sourceforge.net/), and it seems to be popular. Its feature list explicitly mentions extracting files from HTTP streams, so I'd start there.